# Siebel Read From File - xml without siebel envelope

Tags: siebel

Need your help. I would like to read an XML file using BS: EAI XML Read from File Method: ReadEAIMsg. However, the xml message that I'm going to read doesn't have a siebel message envelope " which is needed for this business service to work. How am I going to make this work to be able to read and get the content of the XML file?

Answer (score 0):

BS: 'EAI XML Read from File' does have two other methods which can be used to read XMLs if the SiebelMessage hierarchy is not present. But how you proceed from there to insert/update that message into Siebel matters. You could have a workflow:

1: Use "ReadXMLHier" method of BS:"EAI XML Read from File". Output goes into process property of type Hierarchy

2: Use a datamapper (BS:EAI Data Transformation Engine) to convert this hierarchy into SiebelMessage

3: Use BS:"EAI Siebel Adapter" , Upsert method to upsert this SiebelMessage into Siebel